# Windows 8.1 boot hangs (~120s) in "Session Init"

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, performance

As the title already says, my Windows 8.1 installation take quite some time to boot (without FastBoot).

I managed to record an etl file of the boot process. The result is a very large file: 4.5GB, compressed: 250MB

When viewing this file in the Windows Performance Analyzer, I see that of the 144s boot time, about 120s are spent in "Session Init" phase and for about 90s of that time it is basically doing nothing, with smss.exe using full cpu on one core, and nearly no I/O happening.

Can you recommend a way to analyze the situation?

Comment: upload the compressed file, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3EB502776025218!393&authkey=!ABNDKqJ8hu5dR64&ithint=file%2c.7z)

Comment: you have not captured the correct data. Run this command: **xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+POWER+FILENAME -stackwalk profile+CSwitch+ReadyThread -resultPath C:\TEMP** (this is one line! Copy it into a text file first to make sure it is one line)

Comment: [link](http://sdrv.ms/1c2OZB1)

Comment: the stacks are still missing. Make sure the entry **DisablePagingExecutive** is set to **1** in the Registry (HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management).

Comment: http://sdrv.ms/1ahQcmJ

Comment: still the same issue, the stacks are missing. Have you rebooted after making the change? Also post a picture of the registry key.

Comment: I set the registry value, then executed the command to record the trace -> which triggers a reboot. http://i.imgur.com/7mUaQXN.png

Comment: do a reboot before running the command.

Comment: http://sdrv.ms/18Q6Duq

Comment: still the same. Which WPT version do you use? You MUST use the version from the Windows 8.1 SDK, not older version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891

Comment: http://sdrv.ms/1c3QZbZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing the Registry (`ntdll.dll!ZwInitializeRegistry`) takes a loot of time and causes the CPU usage. From the callstack I can see that the Bitlocker driver is involved (fvevol.sys!FveFilterDeviceControl). Is your HDD encrypted with Bitlocker?  Disable Bitlocker and see if this improves the situation.

Comment: no, I do not use Bitlocker in any way (at least as far as I know)

Comment: In the control center I have "Bitlocker off" for all of my drives.

Comment: I see that the operation which involves the bitlocker driver is to create the hibernation file. Try to turn it off if you don't use the fastBoot or hibernation and look if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, turning off hibernation worked! Any idea why this might be? I thought the hibernation file was created only once?

Comment: I think the file is created again if the size changed.