# How to profile long session initialization during boot process in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, profiling

My computer started to boot for 10 minutes. It has SSD system drive and was booting for 15 seconds previously.

Is it possible to know, what does it doing during this time? The delay occurs before logon screen appears. I mean what I am observing for a long time, is Windows animation of rolling dots. Once logon screen appears, computer works fast. I.e. I need to detalize what happen BEFORE logon screen, not autorunning programs of later stages.

It started suddenly today. First computer hanged in a huge way: it was beeping on mouse move. Very rare type of hang. I have rebooted it hard and it start to boot very slow.

Also it is unable to reboot automatically anymore. Simultaneously, on reboot, I see screen blinking meaning motherboard reboots (?) This tends me thinking it is a hardware-related problem.

**UPDATE**

Windows Performance tools shows, that slow occurs in the stage `Session Init`. Probably `smss.exe` is responsible for this.

[image]

It is just evident, that "session init" takes tremendous time.

**UPDATE 2**

Watching event Event Viewer --> Applications and Service Logs -->Microsoft --> Windows --> Diagnostics - performance -->Operational -->Event ID 100<--

Also indicates session init is guilty:

```
BootTsVersion 2 
  BootStartTime 2015-04-09T22:16:20.819659700Z 
  BootEndTime 2015-04-09T22:23:40.863859000Z 
  SystemBootInstance 154 
  UserBootInstance 150 
  **BootTime 377549** 
  **MainPathBootTime 347049** 
  BootKernelInitTime 39 
  BootDriverInitTime 517 
  BootDevicesInitTime 599 
  BootPrefetchInitTime 0 
  BootPrefetchBytes 0 
  BootAutoChkTime 0 
  **BootSmssInitTime 334923** 
  BootCriticalServicesInitTime 276 
  BootUserProfileProcessingTime 3399 
  BootMachineProfileProcessingTime 639 
  BootExplorerInitTime 4687 
  BootNumStartupApps 47 
  BootPostBootTime 30500 
  BootIsRebootAfterInstall false 
  BootRootCauseStepImprovementBits 0 
  BootRootCauseGradualImprovementBits 0 
  BootRootCauseStepDegradationBits 0 
  BootRootCauseGradualDegradationBits 0 
  BootIsDegradation false 
  BootIsStepDegradation false 
  BootIsGradualDegradation false 
  BootImprovementDelta 0 
  BootDegradationDelta 0 
  BootIsRootCauseIdentified false 
  OSLoaderDuration 600 
  BootPNPInitStartTimeMS 39 
  BootPNPInitDuration 1146 
  OtherKernelInitDuration 795 
  SystemPNPInitStartTimeMS 1932 
  SystemPNPInitDuration 350 
  SessionInitStartTimeMS 2292 
  Session0InitDuration 1751 
  Session1InitDuration 181 
  **SessionInitOtherDuration 332991** 
  WinLogonStartTimeMS 337216 
  OtherLogonInitActivityDuration 1108 
  UserLogonWaitDuration 6582
```

**UPDATE 3**

Found a solution same as here: [Windows 8.1 boot hangs (~120s) in "Session Init"](https://superuser.com/questions/682143/windows-8-1-boot-hangs-120s-in-session-init)

**UPDATE 4**

Salution with hibernate disabling then reenabling helped with boot slow, but didn't help with reboot hang.

Comment: It is much easier than in this referenced supposedly same thread. But since they closed this thread, I cannot post the method. Dims, send me a PM.

Comment: @whs don't see a way to send PMs here :)

Comment: You are right. I just found that out myself. I will post my proposal at this other thread.

Comment: "session init" = initializes the registry, loads and starts the devices and drivers that are not marked BOOT_START, and starts the subsystem processes. if you logged data with the DRIVERS flag, look for a driver that loads slowly.

Comment: @magicandre1981 so, how to know, if it, for example hardware damage of SSD or software corrupt of registry files?

Comment: this can't be detected via xperf/xbootmgr/WPRUI. Capture a reboot trace and look what happens during shutdown: http://pastebin.com/pFVV8Xt7